# MongoDB Update a document's key when another document is updated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Express.js, Node.js, MongoDB, and Mongoose stack

I have three documents in the database which are Warehouses, Inventories, and Items.

A Warehouse has one Inventory, and each Inventory is assigned to a Warehouse.
An Inventory contains many Items.

`items.model.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String
    },
    dateCreated:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    price:{
        type:Number
    },
    type:{
        type:String
    },
    category:{
        type:String
    },
    description:{
        type: String
    },
    picture:{
        type: String
    }
})
const Item = mongoose.model('item',itemSchema)
module.exports.Item=Item
module.exports.itemSchema = itemSchema
```

`inventories.model.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const itemSchema = require('../items/items.model').itemSchema;

const inventorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    dateCreated:{
        type: Date
    },
    items:{
        type:[itemSchema]
    }
})
const Inventory = mongoose.model('inventory',inventorySchema)
module.exports.inventorySchema=inventorySchema;
module.exports.Inventory=Inventory;
```

`warehouses.model.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const inventorySchema = require('../inventories/inventories.model').inventorySchema
const warehouseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String
    },
    location:{
        type:String
    },
    inventory:{
        type:inventorySchema
    },
    dateCreated:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now()
    },
    numberOfEmployees:{
        type:Number
    }
})
const Warehouse = mongoose.model('warehouse',warehouseSchema)
module.exports.Warehouse=Warehouse
```

I have an endpoint which assigns an Inventory to a Warehouse based on the Inventory's name. I also have an endpoint that adds an Item to an Inventory

`warehouses.controller.js`

```
/**
 * 
 * Assign an inventory to warehouse based on
 * Warehouse (id), inventory (name)
 */
const assignInventory = () => async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const inventoryName = req.body.inventory
        const inventoryDoc = await Inventory.findOne({ name: inventoryName })
        if (!inventoryDoc) {
            return res.status(404).json('No Inventory with this ID exists!')
        }
        const warehouseID = req.params.id
        const doc = await Warehouse.findByIdAndUpdate(
            { _id: warehouseID },
            { ...req.body, inventory: inventoryDoc }
        )
        if (!doc) {
            return res.status(404).end()
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Assigned Inventory to warehouse successfully',
            data: doc
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        res.status(400).end()
    }
}
```

`inventories.controller.js`

```
/**
 * 
 * Add an Item to an Inventory based on
 * Inventory (id), Item (name)
 */
const addItemToInventory = () => async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        //Retreive the inventory id from the URL Parameters
        const inventoryID= req.params.id
        //Retreive the item name from the request body
        const itemName= req.body.name;

        //Fetch the item document from the database based on the request body
        const itemDoc = await Item.find({name:itemName})
        if(!itemDoc)
        {
            return res.status(404).json(`Can't find item with this name`)
        }
        console.log(itemDoc)
        //Update the inventory with the the new item document added to its item list
        const inventoryDoc = await Inventory.findById({_id:inventoryID})
        console.log(inventoryDoc)
        var inventoryList = inventoryDoc.items
        console.log('Updated')
        inventoryList.push(itemDoc)
        console.log(inventoryList)

        const updatedInventoryDoc = await Inventory.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:inventoryID},{$push:{items:itemDoc}})
        if(!updatedInventoryDoc){
            return res.status(404).end()
        }
        res.status(200).json({data: updatedInventoryDoc})
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I add an Item to an Inventory that is already assigned to a Warehouse, if I fetched that Warehouse, it will not show the added Item.

[image]

In the image above, I added an `Item` to the `Inventory` and fetched that Inventory.
The Inventory was previously added to a Warehouse.

[image]

Yet as seen above here, The Warehouse still has only one item inside it.

Is there anything that can reference an Inventory inside a Warehouse? so that after any update to any Inventory, the Warehouse will listen to these updates.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: Added Inventory, Warehouse, and Item models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I found out that I should change the structure of the `warehouse.model.js` to make it referring to the `ObjectID` of an `Inventory`, so it is going to look like this.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const inventorySchema = require('../inventories/inventories.model').inventorySchema
const warehouseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String
    },
    location:{
        type:String
    },
    //Instead of inventory:inventorySchema
    inventory:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "inventory"
    },
    dateCreated:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now()
    },
    numberOfEmployees:{
        type:Number
    }
})
const Warehouse = mongoose.model('warehouse',warehouseSchema)
module.exports.Warehouse=Warehouse
```

and inside the `warehouses.controller.js`, we should call `populate` on any database call that retrieves the `Warehouse` documents like this

```
const readWarehouse = () => async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const doc = await Warehouse.find({}).populate('inventory')
        if (!doc) {
            return res.status(404).end()
        }
        res.status(200).json({ data: doc })
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        res.status(400).end()
    }
}

const readOneWarehouse = () => async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const id = req.params.id
        const doc = await Warehouse.findOne({ _id: id }).populate('inventory')
        if (!doc) {
            return res.status(404).end()
        }
        res.status(200).json({ data: doc })
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        res.status(400).end()
    }
}
```

Also updated the `assignInventory()` to be like that

```
const assignInventory = () => async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const inventoryName = req.body.inventory
        const inventoryDoc = await Inventory.findOne({ name: inventoryName })
        if (!inventoryDoc) {
            return res.status(404).json('No Inventory with this ID exists!')
        }
        const inventoryDocID=inventoryDoc._id
        const warehouseID = req.params.id
        const doc = await Warehouse.findByIdAndUpdate(
            { _id: warehouseID },
            { ...req.body, inventory: inventoryDocID }
        )
        if (!doc) {
            return res.status(404).end()
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Assigned Inventory to warehouse successfully',
            data: doc
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        res.status(400).end()
    }
}
```